# Fiddler Composer format for HttpGet Request

Tags: get, request, fiddler

This should be an API 101 question.  I'm stuck.  I have a working hosted API that accepts an HttpGet request to return a simple "Hello" response.  My ASP.Net app works, but I can't seem to test this using Fiddler (and then move to an Android App).  The ASP web service declares:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "SayHello/{userId}")]
    string SayHello(int userId);
```

I cannot figure out what format to use for the Get request:  I've tried:
In Fiddler I compose a localhost test as:

```
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc?SayHello  (returns wdsl page)
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc/SayHello  (returns 400 error)
http://localhost:51276/AppWebService.svc?SayHello&userId=1000 (returns wdsl)
```

So, I'm not sure what I'm 'composing' wrong.